# Which layout to use for a 2x2 image-based menu?

Tags: android, layout, image-scaling

I am trying to create a screen (in portrait mode) that shows 4 images (same size, intended to scale down to fit screen), taking up the entire screen, breaking up the screen into quadrants (a tall, 2x2 grid).  This will act as a main menu type of activity and each image should be clickable, in order to take the user to a different activity.

I have tried using a GridView inside a LinerLayout (using a lot from Google's GridView tutorial) but cannot get the images to all scale properly to fill the entire screen.  I get extra margins around the images and/or scrolling of the entire screen.

I have also tried using a TableLayout, placing 2 images in each of the 2 rows.  Visually, that worked perfectly.  Unfortunately when using that, I cannot seem to reference the ImageView items in the TableLayout in my activity code (findViewById always returns null).

I feel like a TableLayout is really not the "right thing to do" but I would like to hear what others have to say.  Either way, what should be done to accomplish my desired functionality?

Thanks.

Edit 1.1:
The relative layout works much better for getting things lined up.  Now I'm just left with the issue where findViewById always returns null.  Here is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/homescreen_bgcolor"
        >
    <ImageView id="@+id/one"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:src="@drawable/item1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView id="@+id/two"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:src="@drawable/item2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView id="@+id/three"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:src="@drawable/item3"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView id="@+id/four"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:src="@drawable/item4"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

public class HomeScreenActivity2 extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen2);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);


    imageView.setClickable(true);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("Test", "test");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a TableLayout could work for you, but I'd recommend trying out [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) as well. You can basically pin your images to the four quadrants by using combinations of

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`
```

on your images.

I'm doing something similar in my app where I have multiple buttons on a homepage that can launch corresponding activities.  RelativeLayout works fine, and it avoids nested Layout objects, which can hamper performance during render and layout procedures (if it gets out of hand).

Comment: I gave it a try and am still having trouble.  I've posted an edit to my original post.  See Edit 1 above.

Comment: I have figured out my issue with the findViewById:  I was overlooking a mistake in the id attribute.  Rather than id="@+id/four"
 I needed android:id="@+id/four".  Things are working well now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample layout showing how you can achieve a 2 X 2 grid that covers the entire screen using just a RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#42A5F5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#EF5350"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/two"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#66BB6A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/three"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#5C6BC0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/four"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView></RelativeLayout>
```

The above layout results in this:
[image]